# Can't get rid of invisible padding / white space to allow text to wrap under button

Tags: html, css, forms, button, whitespace

I am a beginner to html and css and need help with a small problem I'm facing. On this website I am redesigning, I have three button form (Donate, Find and Subscribe). I want the paragraph beneath the Donate and Find buttons to fit where the white space appears. I have tried all of the margin/padding/border:0 auto; resets and nothing is working. I have a feeling its something to do with the float and clear properties as well as the div the buttons are within (the subscribe button is bigger than the other two buttons so could be the causal problem). Here is the link to my site: http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/
Please use right click/inspect element to see the code.

Really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please paste relevant code here so we can help faster and links also can stop working and later this question will make no sense. Anyways the problem is your HTML structure. You have the 3 buttons inside a div that don't allow the next div that has the text to fit with them because the subscribe btn is bigger.

Comment: As @JoelAlmeida said, create separate `div` for each button and than arrange the other `div` accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding some extra div's and fixing some CSS.

Look how I did it with this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPWybE

HTML:

```
<div class="section group">
    <div class="subgroup1">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            <a href="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/shop.html" class="button"> Donate <p> Furniture and Electricals </p> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            <a href="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/shop.html" class="button"> Find <p> your nearest store </p> </a>
        </div>
      <p>
      Slate was set up to run environmentally friendly projects for the benefit of the local community, and offer work opportunities to people with learning difficulties. Our charity is divided into two main sections of which are the two Feel Good Furniture Shops and the Feel Good Cafe. Please browse our website to find out more about us, donate your unwanted furniture or take a look at our stock catalogue to redecorate your living space!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="subgroup2">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            <form action="" method="post" class="subscribe-form">
                <h4> Subscribe to our blog! </h4>
                <label>
                    <span> Name </span>
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="full" <="" label="">

                    <label>
                        <span> Email </span>
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.co.uk" <="" label="">

                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="button" class="button4" value="Send">

                    </label>
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* NEW CSS */
.group{width:100%;}
.subgroup1{ 
    height:200px;
    width: 64.54%;
    float:left;
}
.subgroup1 .col{width:48%;}
.subgroup2{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
.subgroup2 .col{width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `subscribe to our blog` element out of the `.section group` .

The height of this element is creating the white-space you're wanting to remove beneath the `Donate` and `Find` buttons.